# C++ unsized array in struct, error: "too many initializers"

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, arduino, initialization

```
struct led {
  const int loc;
  int state;
  unsigned int stateDuration [];
  int stateMode;
  unsigned long timestamp;
  } led1 = {D0, 0, {500}, 0, 0},
    led2 = {D7, 0, {100, 900, 400}, 0, 0};
```

This gives me a compilation error "too many initializers" (the array size is 0). Is it possible to declare an unsized array in the structure and then initialize it with varying values like in my example, or must I explicitly declare the array to the maximum size needed?

Comment: @BaummitAugen Thank you for responding, but your comment does not address my question. My goal at the moment is not to learn C++, but to fix this issue.

Comment: If that was supposed to be an answer, I would have posted it as an answer. Instead, it was general commentary on your code, and thus posted as a comment.

Comment: What are `D0` and `D7`?

Comment: This is why gcc should turn *off* that dang option of allowing illegal C++ to compile, and only have it turned on if the programmer specifies it.  Having that option on by default just leads too many (new) C++ programmers into writing code that isn't C++.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Oh, then you are simply mistaken—I am not trying to learn C++.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru This is a variant of C++ for Arduino family microcontrollers. Those values represent memory addresses for hardware pins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with GCC, using one its C++ language extensions, but only with the very last element of your struct, because the offsets of fields have to be constant.
See: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html

> GCC allows static initialization of flexible array members. This is equivalent to defining a new structure containing the original structure followed by an array of sufficient size to contain the data. E.g. in the following, f1 is constructed as if it were declared like f2.
>
> ```
> struct f1 {
>   int x; int y[];
> } f1 = { 1, { 2, 3, 4 } };
> ```

If you are using something else, you can still implement the idea, but only with heap-allocated objects (so the initializer block thing will not be possible) and you will need an own `new` operator taking care of the dynamic part. (Perhaps `delete` too, I am not sure)

Answer (score 3):

It is illegal to have an array of unknown bound as a non-static member of a struct. [class.mem]/13

> Non-static data members shall not have incomplete types.

This is because the size of the class must be known when the closing brace is reached.

Maybe you should make `stateDuration` a `std::vector<unsigned int>` instead.

Comment: There is no `std::vector` in Arduino.